# No suitable driver in Luminus H2 Guestbook app

Tags: clojure, leiningen, luminus

Trying to create the simple example app from Leiningen with Luminus template and H2 db.  Nothing fancy, I literally see tons of examples doing this but always get `No suitable driver`.

```
lein new luminus guestbook +h2
cd guestbook
lein run
```

```
Syntax error (SQLException) compiling at (/private/var/folders/g2/tw6c1syn2hl_915p0xgc2hcm0000gn/T/form-init682714741074384097.clj:1:124).
No suitable driver

Full report at:
/var/folders/g2/tw6c1syn2hl_915p0xgc2hcm0000gn/T/clojure-2526208820906376199.edn
```

That file contains:

```
{:clojure.main/message
 "Syntax error (SQLException) compiling at (/private/var/folders/g2/tw6c1syn2hl_915p0xgc2hcm0000gn/T/form-init682714741074384097.clj:1:124).\nNo suitable driver\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/phase :compile-syntax-check,
  :clojure.error/line 1,
  :clojure.error/column 124,
  :clojure.error/source "form-init682714741074384097.clj",
  :clojure.error/path
  "/private/var/folders/g2/tw6c1syn2hl_915p0xgc2hcm0000gn/T/form-init682714741074384097.clj",
  :clojure.error/class java.sql.SQLException,
  :clojure.error/cause "No suitable driver"},
 :clojure.main/trace
 {:via
  [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException,
    :message
    "Syntax error compiling at (/private/var/folders/g2/tw6c1syn2hl_915p0xgc2hcm0000gn/T/form-init682714741074384097.clj:1:124).",
    :data
    {:clojure.error/phase :compile-syntax-check,
     :clojure.error/line 1,
     :clojure.error/column 124,
     :clojure.error/source
     "/private/var/folders/g2/tw6c1syn2hl_915p0xgc2hcm0000gn/T/form-init682714741074384097.clj"},
    :at [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7652]}
   {:type java.lang.RuntimeException,
    :message "could not start [#'guestbook.db.core/*db*] due to",
    :at [mount.core$up$fn__441 invoke "core.cljc" 80]}
   {:type java.lang.RuntimeException,
    :message
    "Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://twcrone",
    :at
    [com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource
     <init>
     "DriverDataSource.java"
     114]}
   {:type java.sql.SQLException,
    :message "No suitable driver",
    :at [java.sql.DriverManager getDriver "DriverManager.java" 298]}],
  :trace
  [[java.sql.DriverManager getDriver "DriverManager.java" 298]
   [com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource
    <init>
    "DriverDataSource.java"
    106]
   [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase
    initializeDataSource
    "PoolBase.java"
    325]
   [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase <init> "PoolBase.java" 114]
   [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool <init> "HikariPool.java" 108]
   [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    <init>
    "HikariDataSource.java"
    81]
   [hikari_cp.core$make_datasource invokeStatic "core.clj" 268]
   [hikari_cp.core$make_datasource invoke "core.clj" 265]
   [conman.core$connect_BANG_ invokeStatic "core.clj" 162]
   [conman.core$connect_BANG_ invoke "core.clj" 158]
   [guestbook.db.core$eval13387$fn__13388 invoke "core.clj" 10]
   [mount.core$record_BANG_ invokeStatic "core.cljc" 74]
   [mount.core$record_BANG_ invoke "core.cljc" 73]
   [mount.core$up$fn__441 invoke "core.cljc" 81]
   [mount.core$up invokeStatic "core.cljc" 80]
   [mount.core$up invoke "core.cljc" 78]
   [mount.core$bring invokeStatic "core.cljc" 247]
   [mount.core$bring invoke "core.cljc" 239]
   [mount.core$start invokeStatic "core.cljc" 289]
   [mount.core$start doInvoke "core.cljc" 281]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 397]
   [mount.core$start_with_args invokeStatic "core.cljc" 389]
   [mount.core$start_with_args doInvoke "core.cljc" 385]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 410]
   [guestbook.core$start_app invokeStatic "core.clj" 52]
   [guestbook.core$start_app invoke "core.clj" 51]
   [guestbook.core$_main invokeStatic "core.clj" 75]
   [guestbook.core$_main doInvoke "core.clj" 59]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 397]
   [clojure.lang.Var invoke "Var.java" 380]
   [user$eval18339 invokeStatic "form-init682714741074384097.clj" 1]
   [user$eval18339 invoke "form-init682714741074384097.clj" 1]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7181]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7171]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7640]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler loadFile "Compiler.java" 7578]
   [clojure.main$load_script invokeStatic "main.clj" 475]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invoke "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$initialize invokeStatic "main.clj" 508]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 542]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invoke "main.clj" 539]
   [clojure.main$main invokeStatic "main.clj" 664]
   [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 616]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 137]
   [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 705]
   [clojure.main main "main.java" 40]],
  :cause "No suitable driver",
  :phase :compile-syntax-check}}
```

And I've tried all sorts of variations on this from other examples.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I would if there was more to it.  I've seen this type of error on the JVM before, the driver class is not being loaded.  I just don't know how lien/luminous is supposed to do that.  I figured there was a simple thing I missed.

Comment: I tried it on my work laptop and it appears to work fine.  Something is borked on my old personal laptop.  Very weird.  Do I delete this question?

Comment: In any event, I had a borked setup.  On my newer work laptop, it just worked out of the box.  But Biped Phil's answer was on point after I messed around with config in bad ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the error message in the edn file: where it cites the problem database as "jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://twcrone".  That is not an H2 database reference, so your Luminus project, with only the h2 driver on the classpath, would have trouble with it.

Comment: Yeah, I had changed that when trying to connect to postgres and cause H2 connection didn't seem to be working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran `lein new luminus guestbook +h2` then `cd guestbook` and `lein run` and (after downloading a lot of libraries) it starts the web server as expected and browsing `http://127.0.0.1:3000` displays the Luminus web app.

Can you share the exact steps you took that give you that error?

Comment: Haha...there are no "steps", I tried to generate a luminous app with h2 and then ran it.  The driver is obviously not getting pulled in correctly or no "Class.forName..." being done by the framework.  I figured there might be a step missing in the tutorial because it should just work.  I'll dig more.  Maybe my leiningen install is borked for some reason.

Comment: See Biped Phill's answer -- The :database-url is set in the dev-config.edn and test-config.edn files and by default that should be:

:database-url "jdbc:h2:./guestbook_dev.db" ; and .._test.db

so it looks like you had edited one or both of these EDN files?

Comment: Sure, wasn't really the issue but gave him cred for the answer.  I did edit it but was just changing stuff that really wasn't the issue.  Issue really was something with my old laptop's lein/clojure setup.  Not sure what it was but like I said, my newer clean install on my work laptop, everything worked outta the box.  Thanks.